# Vuejs Option. Get an ID from a selected item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, selector

I'm actually using VueJS and encountered a little problem

I have a selector, that needs to memorize an ID to be sent in an axios request later. In the "selected" var, we need to keep only the name of the "type" for user friendly reasons. So, I need to get the ID selected by the user without displaying it. Actually, the code looks like this.

```
<select v-model="selected">
 <label for="lg_type" class="sr-only">Type de personnage</label>
  <option disabled value="">Choisir un type</option>
  <option v-for="onetype in playertype" class="form-control" id="lg_type" name="lg_type" v-bind:key="onetype.idType">
      {{onetype.idType}}-{{ onetype.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Selected is the actual name of the selected type. Since it's vue, when I click on another Type from my selector, it changes it automatically

onetype contains two things : A name, and an idType
playertype contains an array of all types

As we can see in the code, i display things like this "idType - name", but I only want to display "name" (so just erase onetype.idType), but I need to get the id to send it elswhere (I can't use onetype.idType to get the id to my axios method)

I don't know if it's clear enough, but I need to send the onetype.idType to an axios method, but I can't use it this way.

Thanks you in advance, this is driving me crazy and I feel I've missed something obvious ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value` attribute and you will get it in `v-model` instead of displayed option:

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <label for="lg_type" class="sr-only">Type de personnage</label>
  <option disabled value="">Choisir un type</option>
  <option 
    v-for="onetype in playertype" 
    :value="onetype.idType"
    class="form-control"
    id="lg_type"
    name="lg_type"
    v-bind:key="onetype.idType"
  >{{ onetype.idType }}-{{ onetype.name }}</option>
</select>
```